# Oracle DDL Trigger error - RDSADMIN.RDS_DDL_TRIGGER

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

On Oracle 11g, While calling a procedure through web application, which creates a temporary table inside, I am facing an error as RDSADMIN.RDS_DDL_TRIGGER error. While searching for this issue, we found that RDSDMIN is the system user created by default but nothing else. Surprisingly running the same procedure from the oracle developer it runs successfully. Can i have any other information regarding the same?